# How to properly manage dynamically allocated pointer arrays in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, free

Currently I'm working on a microprocessor that only has a small RAM capacity (128 MB). I'm running multiple threads of execution to analyze performance but the essence of the problem lies on storing large amounts of data (floats and integers) in dynamic space in order to reduce the possibility of data copy/allocation that data structures such as vectors tend to rely on in execution.

I decided to test some possible schemes on how to tackle this in CLion. I wrote the following code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>


int initial_capacity = 3;
int current_capacity = 3;
int current_count  = 0;

int*** initializeArray(){
    // initialize triple array space in memory
    int*** arr;
    /*
       3 items -> 3 data sets -> each data set starts with 3 spaces
       a "int arr[3][3][3]" but dynamically allocated
    */
    arr = (int***) calloc(current_capacity, sizeof(int**));
    for(int i = 0; i < current_capacity; i++){
        arr[i] = (int**) calloc(current_capacity, sizeof(int*));
        for(int j =0; j < current_capacity; j++){
            arr[i][j] = (int*) calloc(current_capacity,sizeof(int));
        }
    }
    return arr;
}


void resizeArray(int *** arr){
    auto max = (double) current_capacity;
    double percentage = current_count/max;
    if(percentage >= 0.5){
        for (int i = 0; i < initial_capacity; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < initial_capacity; ++j) {
                current_capacity*=2;
                arr[i][j] = (int*) realloc(arr[i][j],(current_capacity)*sizeof(int));
            }
        }
    }
}

void deleteArrays(int *** arr){
    for (int i = 0; i < initial_capacity; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < initial_capacity; ++j) {
            for (int k = 0; k < current_count; ++k) {
                arr[i][j][k] = NULL;
            }

        }
    }
    printf("Releasing allocated arrays 1\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < initial_capacity; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < initial_capacity; ++j) {
            arr[i][j] = (int*) realloc(arr[i][j],sizeof(int));
            free(arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("Releasing allocated arrays 2\n");

    for (int i = 0;  i < initial_capacity; ++i) {
        free(arr[i]);
    }
    printf("Releasing allocated arrays 3\n");

    free(arr);
}


void printArrays(int *** arr){
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        printf("Array[%d]\n", i);
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
            printf("Array[%d][%d]\nElements: ", i, j);
            for (int k = 0; k < current_count; ++k) {
                printf(" %d", arr[i][j][k]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    int *** generated= initializeArray();
    int count  = 0;
    while (count < 21){
        if(count % 3 == 0) printArrays(generated);
        //verify
        resizeArray(generated);
        generated[0][0][current_count] = rand();
        generated[0][1][current_count] = rand();
        generated[0][2][current_count] = rand();
        generated[1][0][current_count] = rand();
        generated[1][1][current_count] = rand();
        generated[1][2][current_count] = rand();
        generated[2][0][current_count] = rand();
        generated[2][1][current_count] = rand();
        generated[2][2][current_count] = rand();

        current_count++;
        count++;
    }
    /* some operation with data collected */
    deleteArrays(generated);
    printf("Finished deleting dynamic arrays");
    return 0;
}
```

I attempted to generate a triple array in order to keep storing the same amount of information in the last subset while it kept increasing in size and total amount. However, the delete procedure of the array in order to complete the dynamic aspect of the process always results in *Process finished with exit code -1073740940 (0xC0000374)* which is a heap corruption error. I'm not super familiar with this and any feedback on it would be helpful.

Comment: Did you try adding debugging statements to print the raw pointers of every allocated/reallocated/deleted array? Based on that you should be able to detect any bad deletions. If everything lines up use a static memory analysis tool to find memory corruption.

Comment: Do not ask about both C and C++ at once except for questions involving differences or interactions between the languages. Since the code has `#include` statements that will not work in C, I am deleting the C tag.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I've looked at some possible statements but usually the only ones I've managed to use are in reference to the first item of the address and in all instances it returns a valid element. Not sure how to verify in the rest of the allocated spaces

Comment: Is it really necessary to have a 3 dimensional array with 3 different calloc calls? Is there a good reason to not use just a one dimensional array and do the rest with index shifts? Sometimes having one big block of allocation makes your life dramatically easier. Also you then may reap some benefits of cache locality, depending on the microprocessor :)

Comment: @hakononakani It's a concept that I wasn't aware of. Usually I've only managed n-arrays in a iterative sequence. I'll look into it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The routine `resizeArray` doubles `current_capacity` with `current_capacity*=2;` in each iteration of its inner loop. The first time it is called, this results in `arr[0][0]` being set to point to memory for 6 `int`, while the loops continue and ultimately leave `current_capacity` set to 1536. For the rest of program execution, `resizeArray` never allocates more memory, due to the fact that its threshold relative to `current_capacity` is never reached.

Meanwhile, the `main` routine continues writing more and more elements to `generated[0][0]`, increasing `current_count` up to 20 and therefore writing beyond the bounds of the allocated memory.

This bug can be fixed by moving `current_capacity*=2;` out of the loops, to just inside the “then” block of `if(percentage >= 0.5)`.

Also note that the technique of implementing multidimensional arrays as pointers-to-pointers or pointers-to-pointers-to-pointers is inefficient in time and space. “Pointer chasing” is bad for speculative execution of instructions by the processor. For fixed-size multidimensional arrays, this is not used in production-quality code. In this case where a variable last dimension is desired, the choice is a little less clear, but it still may be preferable to use one contiguous memory allocation and to use index arithmetic to calculate locations in the array rather than pointer lookups. (C makes this fairly simple with variable length arrays, although support for them is optional. C++ implementations may provide variable length arrays as an extension, but the necessary arithmetic is not hard and can be done with helper functions or classes.)